# EMail enconding Hybris

Tags: email, action, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to send an email using the sendEmail action.
Everything goes well excepts for the email encoding. I need it to be UTF-8 but I can't find how set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default encoding should be UTF-8. Have a look at

```
de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.email.impl.DefaultEmailService
```

in the method

```
public boolean send(final EmailMessageModel message)
```

and:

```
protected String getBody(final EmailMessageModel message)
```

The only reason I would see, is that UTF-8 is not supported by your system. But that doesn't sound very likely.

Maybe you imported the template in the wrong encoding? The template for email subject and body is an attribute of the EmailPageTemplate. Look it up in hmc/backoffice in WCMS/Page templates. Restrict the search to Email Page Templates. Find your Template. The tab Administration holds the related templates. The attributes are called Html Email Template and Email Subject. Right click them and select edit (in new window) to view the content.

You can look up your templates for cms components in your email page in hmc/backoffice in system/output documents/communication templates.

The default code for a component is:

```
<siteUid>-<Component Typecode>-template
```

e.g.

```
mysite-CMSParagraphComponent-template
```

If the content is not correct, change it in hmc/backoffice or reimport it. An impex file would look like this:

```
$emailResource=jar:de.hybris.mystore.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/mystorecore/import/emails
$lang=en

UPDATE RendererTemplate;code[unique=true];description[lang=$lang];templateScript[lang=$lang,translator=de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.FileLoaderValueTranslator]
# Import MyCmsComponent for mystore
;mystore-MyCmsComponent-template;"MyCmsComponent Template";$emailResource/email-myCmsComponentTemplate.vm
# Import MyEmail Content
;mystore_My_Email_Body;"My Email Body";$emailResource/email-myEmailBody.vm
;mystore_My_Email_Subject;"My Email Subject";$emailResource/email-myEmailSubject.vm
```

Now make sure, that the files email-myCmsComponentTemplate.vm, email-myEmailBody.vm and email-myEmailSubject.vm in the directory mystorecore/import/emails are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Your are right!!. Looks like the template got imported in the wrong encoding. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Either you change the content in hmc/backoffice, or you reimport the files. Make sure that the files are stored in the right encoding.

Comment: Check the edit to my answer. I added example impex code to import renderer templates.